# Using Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging Provider for Service Stack

Tags: .net, rest, servicestack, enterprise-library-5

I have a project based on ServiceStack framework and I want to use the Logging provider for  Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0, here are the steps I followed:

(1) Installed the Service Logging provider for MS Enterprise Library 5.0:
     Install-Package ServiceStack.Logging.EnterpriseLibrary5

(2) Created a file EntLib.Config in the project with the content https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Logging.Tests/entlib5.test.config

(3) In the service app host configured LogFactory to use EntLib5Factroy:

```
 public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
 {
     LogManager.LogFactory = new EntLib5Factory(<Path-to-above-EntLib.config-file>);
     SetConfig(new EndPointHostConfig(DebugMode = true });
 }
```

After launching the application I can see the error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

---

The DebugFormat method is not supported. Modify the Log Message Format using a formatter in the loggingConfiguration section.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The DebugFormat method is not supported. Modify the Log Message Format using a formatter in the loggingConfiguration section.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NotSupportedException: The DebugFormat method is not supported. Modify the Log Message Format using a formatter in the loggingConfiguration section.]
   ServiceStack.Logging.EntLib5.EntLib5Logger.DebugFormat(String format, Object[] args) +96
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: Exception is being thrown from here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.EnterpriseLibrary5/EntLib5Logger.cs#L146 .